# Can multiple lines of code execute at a random time in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, time

So I just wonder, if I have something like this:

```
var arr = [4,3,2,2]

setTimeout(function() {
  arr.push(3)
}, 2) // 2 MS
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr.splice(i, 1)
  arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 2)
}
```

Is it possible that the timeout can execute anytime under the time of the loop, depending on how fast the JS is executed, or does the timeout wait for the loop to end or something?

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded. So: No. (Hint: `setTimeout()` *tries* to keep the timeout, but there's no guarantee.)